# Datastore dump of nested json returns strange characters

Tags: ckan

I have a datastore resource that I'm trying to dump to CSV format using the /datastore/dump/[resource-id] url.
The problem is that any nested json within my resource will be formatted beginning with a "u"-character:

Example:

```
_id,measureId,lastUpdated,validFrom,validTo,publiclyAvailableInformation,regionalIndicator,subCategoryDefinition,parentMeasureDefinition,author,authenticator
105,02c0ac9c-b26c-449c-b064-2a2da84fa763,2016-05-26T10:04:23,,,False,{},"{u'parentMeasureId': u'e101817d-2226-4f48-a1d2-fcb61fde050e', u'subCategoryCode': [{u'code': u'545779e637874129a8ef8af5', u'system': u'5457794537874129a8ef8aaf'}]}",,,
```

see `{u'parentMeasureId'`in the second row and in all athe other nested json types. The "u"-character is not in the original resource and if I access the reource using the usual datastore API it is returned ok:

```
{
"validFrom": null,
"measureId": "053eb6bf-3da5-4264-a056-87dc4deb3075",
"author": null,
"subCategoryDefinition": {
"parentMeasureId": "a87440aa-30c5-43f0-9e51-d07f5fccc131",
"subCategoryCode": [
{
"code": "fb9376b6-12fa-47b4-8a2a-031657a72a0d",
"system": "19bb7abe-7de4-420f-8259-7aca0a461b6f"
}
]
}
```

Does anyone know what the datastore/dump doest to the resource and why this happens?

Comment: This looks like a bug. The object is being dumped as the Python representation and not as JSON. Can you open an issue here with the CKAN version you are using and this example?https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I´ve opened the issue, #3477.
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3477